# Problems with ForEach extension method over IEnumerable<Request.Files>

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, extension-methods, ienumerable

While doing some basic validation on the ASP.Net (4.0) `Request.Files` (upload) collection I decided to try it with LINQ.

The collection is `IEnumerable<T>` and so doesn't offer ForEach. Foolishly I decided to build an extension method that would do the job. Sorry to say not so much success...

Running the extension method (below) raises next error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'

There is clearly something I am not getting, but I can't see what it is, so at the risk of looking like an idiot (wont be the first time) here is the code in 3 chunks, along with a promise of gratitude for any help.

First, the extension method with an Action parameter:

```
//Extend ForEach to IEnumerated Files
public static IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileWrapper> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileWrapper> source, Action<HttpPostedFileWrapper> action)
{
   //breaks on first 'item' init
   foreach (HttpPostedFileWrapper item in source)
        action(item);
    return source;
}
```

The error occurs when the internal foreach loop hits the 'item' in  'source'.

Here is the calling code (variables MaxFileTries and attachPath are properly set previously) :

```
var files = Request.Files.Cast<HttpPostedFile>()
    .Select(file => new HttpPostedFileWrapper(file))
    .Where(file => file.ContentLength > 0
        && file.ContentLength <= MaxFileSize
        && file.FileName.Length > 0)
    .ForEach<HttpPostedFileWrapper>(f => f.SaveUpload(attachPath, MaxFileTries));
```

And lastly, the Action target, Saving the upload file - we don't appear to ever even get to here, but just in case, here it is:

```
public static HttpPostedFileWrapper SaveUpload(this HttpPostedFileWrapper f, string attachPath, int MaxFileTries)
{
    // we can only upload the same file MaxTries times in one session
    int tries = 0;
    string saveName = f.FileName.Substring(f.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);   //strip any local
    string path = attachPath + saveName;
    while (File.Exists(path) && tries <= MaxFileTries)
    {
        tries++;
        path = attachPath + " (" + tries.ToString() + ")" + saveName;
    }
    if (tries <= MaxFileTries)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(attachPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(attachPath);
        f.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return f;
}
```

I confess that some of the above is a cobbling together of "bits found", so I am likely getting what I deserve, but if anyone has a good understanding of (or has at least been through) this, maybe I can learn something.

Thanks for any.

Comment: ok I tried this: `Request.Files.Cast<HttpPostedFile>().Select(file => new HttpPostedFileWrapper(file)).Where( file => file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength <= MaxFileSize && file.FileName.Length > 0).ToList<HttpPostedFileWrapper>().ForEach(file=>file.SaveUpload(attachPath,MaxFileTries) );` with the same result

Comment: Why do you need the `T` in `ForEach<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just call `ToList().ForEach()` on the original `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: lol, and i was having so much fun.... durr.. yes that will probably solve the original problem, but I still would like to figure out how it would be done... its turned into a challenge ;-)

Comment: k - I see what you mean. I also read here though: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx  - so, I am not the only one trying this and the debate seems lively as to whether it is worthwhile. At the end of the day simple extensions inside a normal ForEach loop seems to be clearer, but if its to be done then a generic IEnumerable extension (see abatishchev's first code segment below) seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

Your class that extends `HttpFileCollection` should be

```
  public static class HttpPostedFileExtension
  {
    //Extend ForEach to IEnumerated Files
    public static void ProcessPostedFiles(this HttpFileCollection source, Func<HttpPostedFile, bool> predicate, Action<HttpPostedFile> action)
    {
      foreach (var item in source.AllKeys)
      {
        var httpPostedFile = source[item];
        if (predicate(httpPostedFile))
          action(httpPostedFile);
      }
    }  
  }
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
  Request.Files.ProcessPostedFiles(
  postedFile =>
  {
    return (postedFile.ContentLength > 0 && postedFile.FileName.Length > 0);      
  },
  pFile =>
  {
    //Do something with pFile which is an Instance of HttpPosteFile
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! I think i understand that, but in the usage you gave wouldn't Request.Files.PostedFiles() execute for each 'file' before the content length an name are checked? If so then the extension methods can't really perform the save.. or am i missing something?

Comment: @Serexx, Ok, I think I get what you're trying to do. Hang on, I'll edit my answer with new code.

Comment: @Shiv @Serexx How to reproduce a scenario when `Request.Files` contains more then 1 item?

Comment: @abatishchev, I'm afraid I don't understand your question

Comment: When I used `<asp:FileUpload>`, it supports only a single file to upload, so `Request.Files` contains only 1 item - the file chosen.

Comment: @abatishchev, you need to use multiple controls to allow multiple files to be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

First, write a common extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
   foreach (T item in source)
        action(item);
    return source; // or void, without return
}
```

Then, `Request.Files` is castable to `IEnumerable<string>`, not `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFile>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> requestFiles = this.Request.Files.Cast<string>();
```

but indeed `System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.PostedFile` is `HttpPostedFile`:

```
HttpPostedFile file = fileUpload.PostedFile;
HttpPostedFileWrapper wrapper = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(file);
```

but it's single, not a collection. Where from did you get your collection?

---

Another extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<HttpPostedFile> ToEnumerable(this HttpFileCollection collection)
{
    foreach (var item in collection.AllKeys)
    {
        yield return collection[item];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFile> files = this.Request.Files.ToEnumerable();
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileWrapper> wrappers = files.Select(f => new HttpPostedFileWrapper(f));
```

Comment: ok, the generic extension makes more sense to me now but HttpPostedFile has properties I need in my delegated function. The Collection is the Request.Files collection. Actually I had a read here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx 

looks like your generic extension is the answer, but attached to the collection.

Comment: @Serexx @abatishchev Why does the generic method work but the other does not

Comment: @Midhat: Elaborate your question please

Comment: From your comment, I get that the method created with ForEach<T> and using T as a generic type worked, but it did not work when you specified the type in the method signature. Why?

Comment: @Midhat: Serexx's extenstion method is not correct, because it declares generic type `T` (`ForEach<T>()` but it's used nowhere into method's body. So it even can be non-generic, and will do the same work. Or can be common and generic, and will do the same work for any type. Right?

Comment: @Serexx: I updated my post for another, also useful extension method.